# pgAdmin 4 server mode port

Tags: apache2, pgadmin-4

following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode) tutorial, I've successfully installed pgAdmin4 in server mode. However, pgAdmin4 is accessible by my IP address on the default port. I would like access using another port like the 8081. I've tried by modifying the content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/pgadmin4.conf but without success. Thanks in advance

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
ServerName my_ip

WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25 python-home=/home/user/environments/my_env
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi

<Directory "/home/user/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/">
    WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.

The steps are:

1. Configure Apache to Listen on each of the ports you want to service. Add `Listen 8081` in the ports.conf file.
   `sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf`
2. Modify the content of pgadmin4.conf as follow
   `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/pgadmin4.conf`

Type

```
<VirtualHost my_ip:8081>
ServerName my_ip:8081

WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25 python-home=/home/user/environments/my_env
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi

<Directory "/home/user/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/">
    WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. Restart apache